# How to Separate out the artifacts for multistage deployment in Azure DevOps Yaml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Build pipeline which builds from two branches Dev and main and generate artifacts.
Now I want to run the deploy pipeline based on artifacts and deploy in multiple environments. I am not able to separate out and put the conditions on the deploy stage.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

> I have two separate piplines one is for build and another is for deploy and that deploy pipeline has multiple stages (Dev & Prod). Now the requirement is when Build is generated for Dev then only Dev Stage will run in deploy pipeline and same is for Prod

You can use [Pipeline resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-pipelines-resource) in **Deploy** pipeline to consume the artifact from **build** pipeline. Then you can get the build pipeline source branch from [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pipeline-resource-variables).

[image]

You need a `prestage` to get the build pipeline source branch so that it can determine which stage(Dev or Prod) to deploy.

Yaml sample as below:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MyBuildPipeline
    source: simpleartifact


stages:
- stage: Prestage
  jobs:
  - job: PreJob
    steps:
    - download: MyBuildPipeline   # pipeline resource identifier.
      artifact: test  # artifact to download, optional; defaults to all the artifacts from the resource.

    - bash: |
       echo $(resources.pipeline.MyBuildPipeline.sourceBranch)
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildref;isOutput=true]$(resources.pipeline.MyBuildPipeline.sourceBranch)"
      name: checkref

- stage: Dev
  dependsOn: Prestage
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.Prestage.outputs['Prejob.checkref.buildref'], 'refs/heads/dev1'))
  #condition: eq(dependencies.Prestage.outputs['.build_job.setRunTests.runTests'], 'true')
  jobs:
  - job: dev
    steps:
    - download: MyBuildPipeline 
      artifact: test 


- stage: Prod
  dependsOn: Prestage
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.Prestage.outputs['Prejob.checkref.buildref'], 'refs/heads/main'))
  jobs:
  - job: Prod
    steps:
    - download: MyBuildPipeline 
      artifact: test
```

[image]

[image]

PS: By default, files are downloaded to $(Pipeline.Workspace). please check the link [Download artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#download-artifacts) for the details.

Comment: My Requirement is completely different. I have two separate piplines one is for build and another is for deploy and that deploy pipeline has multiple stages (Dev & Prod). Now the requirement is when Build is generated for Dev then only Dev Stage will run in deploy pipeline and same is for Prod

Comment: Thanks @SudarshanSharma for the clarification. May i know if the build pipeline will trigger the Deploy pipeline? Or it's manual trigger for Deploy pipeline?

Comment: Both Manually and with trigger as well

Comment: I have updated the reply based on the info, please check, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @wade for your reply. I have already tried above solution and in that I am facing one challenge Actually for build pipeline I have two repository one is for DevOps and One is for Code. So when we run the deploy pipeline it takes only DevOps branch not code Branch. if this is fixed then Above solution is the Best fit for my requirement.

Comment: Thanks @SudarshanSharma. It appears it's a little complex in your build pipeline, could you please let me know how the artifact is generated? Pipeline Yaml would be appreciated. And what would you want to determine the Deploy pipeline stage to run? Both DevOps branch and code Branch?

Comment: DevOps Pipelines are in Repo A which is completely separated from Application Code Repo B. Now when team pushes the code it will trigger the pipeline and generated a Docker Image (Dev Branch and Main Branch) Now this we have to push to ACR and then deploy on AKS. Right now everything is happening in the same pipeline so for Rollback prospective. I identify this approach to separate out the build from Deploy. In that we can select the specific build to rollback or redeployment.

Comment: With `pipeline resource variable` (first screenshot), we can get most info of Build pipeline(eg: runid...etc), so we can get all result with build rest api actually. In your comment, i didn't get info about how the artifact is generated. Could you please share a sample yaml? Then it could be more clear and benefit for further checking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256453/discussion-between-sudarshan-sharma-and-wade-zhou-msft).

Comment: - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          ${{ if eq( parameters.Environment, 'Dev') }}: 
            ArtifactName: 'Dev'
          ${{ if eq( parameters.Environment, 'Prod') }}: 
            ArtifactName: 'Prod'
          publishLocation: 'Container'
While publishing with the help of conditions I am generating artifacts